# Two footnotemarks in a tcolorbox yield footnotes with the same label

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

To get the `footnotes` at the bottom of the page rather than at the bottom of the `tcolorbox`, I use `\footnotemark` inside the `tcolorbox` and `\footnotetext` below the `tcolorbox`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}\footnotemark.

And this is some text.\footnotemark. 
\end{tcolorbox}
\footnotetext{This is footnote 1}
\footnotetext{This is footnote 2}
And more text.\footnote{This is footnote 3}
\end{document}
```

and here is the output: (I had to fake it a bit in order to keep the size of the picture reasonable.):

[image: Output]

Note that, at the bottom of the page, Footnote 2 and Footnote 3 are both labelled correctly as 2 and 3 while Footnote 1 is incorrectly labelled 2.

Comment: It would show the same labels without `tcolorbox` as well!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't understand: without `tcolorbox` there is no point using `footnotemark`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But only the first footnote is incorrectly labelled as 2. Footnote 2 and Footnote 3 are labelled correctly as 2 and 3. So, the footnote counter is incremented correctly.

Comment: Yes, I was looking into the wrong code... forget my comment

Comment: I think I could track it down: The problem is that `\footnotemark` increases `footnote`, stores `\@thefnmark` in a global expanded definition, the next `\footnotemark` will overwrite this definition, but `\footnotetext does use only the last value of `\@thefnmark`, it is not aware that there have been multiple `\footnotemark` commands before

Comment: @ChristianHupfer 1. I still think that there is something wrong: with just `\footnote` in the `tcolorbox`, the two footnotes `in` the tcolorbox are labelled `a` and `b` but before Footnote 1 (which is the old Footnote 3) there is now a `0` label without footnote. 2. In any case, how do I solve my problem with the `footnotemarks`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for this problem has nothing to with `tcolorbox` -- `\footnotetext` uses `\@thefnmark` which is overwritten each time `\footnotemark` is applied, so multiple calls of `\footnotemark` will increase the `footnote` counter but there is no association of those footnote counter values with the corresponding `\footnotetext`. 
Multiple specifications of `\footnotetext` do not increase the relevant footnote counter label.

It is possible to use `\footnotetext[value]{...}` instead, which sets the `footnote` counter in a group -- it will not leak outside.

The solution below tracks the number of `\footnotemark` calls and assigns a label to it, `\morefootnotetext` retrieves the label and extracts the counter value, being typeset then with `\footnotetext[value]{...}`.

This approach will fail if there are more `\footnotetext` calls than `\footnotemark` assignments!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{totalfootnotes}
\newcounter{totalfootnotetexts}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters{footnote}{totalfootnotes}% Count all footnotes

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}
\xpatchcmd{\footnotemark}{\stepcounter}{\refstepcounter}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\footnotemark}{\label{fnmark-\number\value{totalfootnotes}}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\footnote}{\stepcounter{totalfootnotetexts}}{}{}% Explicitly step!


\NewDocumentCommand{\morefootnotetext}{o+m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \footnotetext[#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \stepcounter{totalfootnotetexts}%
    \footnotetext[\getrefnumber{fnmark-\number\value{totalfootnotetexts}}]{#2}
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}\footnotemark

And this is some text.\footnotemark
\end{tcolorbox}
\morefootnotetext{This is footnote 1 from inside}
\morefootnotetext{This is footnote 2 from inside}
And more text.\footnote{This is footnote 3 from outside}

Now an example with 4 footnotemark\footnote{A dummy footnote} calls
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}\footnotemark

And this is some text.\footnotemark

Stuff\footnotemark Otherstuff\footnotemark
\end{tcolorbox}
\morefootnotetext{This is footnote 3 from inside}
\morefootnotetext{This is footnote 4 from inside}
\morefootnotetext{This is footnote 5 from inside}
\morefootnotetext{This is footnote 6 from inside}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `manyfoot` will provide another solution

Comment: Error: "kernel/property-unknown"! ! The key property '.value_forbidden:n' is unknown.

Comment: @schremmer: Well, you have to update your TeX distribution then. (Which is very likely you have to do anyway since `tcolorbox` uses `xparse` internally too (in some modules)

Comment: My distribution is `TeXLive-013` and I am afraid I am going to stay with it as my whole set-up--- myself included---is old. So, thanks for trying and since my stuff is open-source, I will leave it as is and to others to fix it.