# Citations in footnotes reffered to tcolorbox content

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, tcolorbox

How to place footcites at the bottom of the slide (see picture below)?

[image]

A bit similar problem was arisen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349929/two-footnotemarks-in-a-tcolorbox-yield-footnotes-with-the-same-label). I tried to adapt [the solution with labeling of footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263693/footnote-in-a-tcolorbox-environment) in which is used the sequence of commands: `\footnote{\label{name}Some footnote text.}` `\footnotemark[\ref{name}]`, but it is not the solution for the `\footcitetexts` command.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,sortcites]{biblatex}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}    % switch off buttons on the slide bottom

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@book{roadrunner,
    author =    {Geococcyx californianus},
    title =     {Gregorian choir}
}
@book{cookiemonster,
    author =    {Blue monster},
    title =     {Astronautics}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Aaa aaa aaa aaa\footcite{roadrunner}.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Bbb bbb bbb bbb\footcites[p. 100]{cookiemonster}[p. 200]{roadrunner}.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

BTW: If needed, is it possible to ensure wrapping of the `\footcites` content to fit it automatically to the box? (In the picture above it exceeds the box boundary.)

EDIT (after comments):
If there are more than one reference in a single tcolorbox then the counters are wrong (at the bottom of the page). Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,sortcites]{biblatex}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}    % switch off buttons on the slide bottom

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@book{roadrunner,
    author =    {Geococcyx californianus},
    title =     {Gregorian choir}
}
@book{cookiemonster,
    author =    {Blue monster},
    title =     {Astronautics}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Aaa aaa aaa aaa\footnotemark

        Ccc ccc ccc ccc\footnotemark.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footcitetext{roadrunner}
    \footcitetext{cookiemonster}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Bbb bbb bbb bbb\footnotemark.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footcitetexts[p. 100]{cookiemonster}[p. 200]{roadrunner}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is a bit similar to the linked one (above). Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `\footnotemark` and `\footcitetext`

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Aaa aaa aaa aaa\footnotemark.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footcitetext{roadrunner}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Bbb bbb bbb bbb\footnotemark.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footcitetexts[100]{cookiemonster}[200]{roadrunner}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Since you are having trouble with consecutive footnotes, get the [`nextfootnote` package by Ijon Tichy from TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/19464/) and use

```
\newcommand*{\mkbibnextfootnotetext}[1]{\nextfootnotetext{\blxmkbibnote{foot}{#1}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibnextfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Aaa aaa aaa aaa\nextfootnotemark\nextfootnotemark
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footcitetext{roadrunner}\footcitetext{roadrunner}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=This is tcolorbox]
        Bbb bbb bbb bbb\nextfootnotemark.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footcitetexts[100]{cookiemonster}[200]{roadrunner}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx for the response. What about the case in which two footcites in one tcolorbox are placed?

Comment: @forrest Not sure if I get your drift, but you can easily have `lorem\footnotemark ipsum\footnotemark` in a `tcolorbox` and then `\footcitetext{sigfridsson}\footcitetext{worman}` after that.

Comment: I put the additional picture to my question. In this picture two records at the page bottom are labeled with number 2 (first should have number 1).

Comment: @forrest This is a common issue, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43692/35864

Comment: I see that David Carlise and Stephen proposed solutions for footnotes, but I don't know how apply it for footcites. The accepted solution given by Ulrike Fischer is not associative.

Comment: Not sure what `\footcitetexts` is and which package it belongs to. Replacing it with `\footnotetext` worked for me.

Comment: @Martin It is a `biblatex` command. The question was specifically about footnote citations produced via `\footcite`. But the general strategy can be applied to normal `\footnote`s as well, in which case `\footcitetext(s)` is simply `\footnotetext`.