# footnote outside tikzbox and tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, tcolorbox

I use `tikz` and `tcolorbox` for theorems. Also **I want footnotes outside of the boxes, at the bottom of the page and with the same numbering like the others**. I want something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22472/tikz-how-to-move-a-footnote-in-a-node-out-of-that-group), but with the numbering style to be the same with the outside footnotes.

Is there any solution?

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{environ}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\Roman{footnote}]}% Footnote style!!!

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\NewEnviron{tikzbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
            \BODY
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewEnviron{Tbox}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
        breakable]
        \BODY
    \end{tcolorbox}
}


\begin{document}

Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text\footnote{The first footnote.}

Other main text Other main text Other main text Other main text\footnote{The second footnote.}

\begin{tikzbox}
Some tikzboxed text Some tikzboxed text Some tikzboxed text\footnote{I want this footnote outside of the box and with number [III].}
\end{tikzbox}

\begin{Tbox}
Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text\footnote{I want this footnote outside of the box and with number [IV].}
\end{Tbox}

\end{document}
```

and this is how it looks like:

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349938/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza , I knew this solution, but it wasn't for me. I want to use `footnote` (not `\footnotemark`) inside `tikz`-box and `ticolorbox`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what *outside the box* means. If you want the footnote just below the box, you could try to use a `bicolor` box where the footnote is the lower part. What follows is not a perfect solution but a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{environ}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{[\Roman{footnote}]}% Footnote style!!!

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\NewEnviron{tikzbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
            \BODY
    \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\NewEnviron{Tbox}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
        breakable,
        bicolor,
        colback=white,
        colbacklower=white,
        fontlower=\footnotesize,
        bottom=1mm,
        middle=1mm,
        frame hidden,
        overlay={\draw[rounded corners] (frame.north west) rectangle (segmentation.south east);},
        ]
        \BODY
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\tcblower \footnotemark #1}



\begin{document}

Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text Some main text\footnote{The first footnote.}

Other main text Other main text Other main text Other main text\footnote{The second footnote.}

\begin{tikzbox}
Some tikzboxed text Some tikzboxed text Some tikzboxed text\footnote{I want this footnote outside of the box and with number [III].}
\end{tikzbox}

\begin{Tbox}
Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text Some tcolorboxed text\myfootnote{I want this footnote outside of the box and with number [IV].}
\end{Tbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the footnotes just like regular footnotes, follow ferahfeza's suggestion.

Comment: I mean that I want them to be at the bottom of the page, like the others footnotes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by Bernard to:
[Footnote outside theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520067/footnote-outside-theorem-environment)
very useful.

Sorry for answering and not commenting, I can't comment yet :(