# Footnote outside theorem environment

Tags: footnotes, theorems, tcolorbox, amsthm, article

I tried to add a footnote in a tcolorbox based theorem environment, which is showing right inside the theorem box. How to position footnote at the bottom of the page?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   Packages Required
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                           tcolorbox and theorem Environment
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {theorem}% name
  {Theorem}% title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
  {thm}% prefix

\makeatletter
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   User defined Commands
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{$f(#1)$}
\newcommand{\tcb@cnt@theoremautorefname}{Theorem}
\makeatother

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{Cauchy's Theorem}{}
Let C be a simple\footnote{A simple curve is one which does not cross itself.}. closed curve with continously turning tangents except possibly at a finite number of of points (otherwise curve must be smooth). If \f{z} is analytic on and inside C, then 
\begin{equation}
\oint_{C} f(z) \, dz = 0
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Can I get a normal footnote in a minipage environment in LaTeX? How?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274/82917) Not an exact duplicate but the  solution using `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` is the same.

Comment: Unrelated: `\f{z}` and `$f(z)$` differ by one keystroke, and yet I believe the second one is much more clear. (Very personal opinion, of course.)

Comment: @campa Yes, but it prevents me from keep pressing dollar sign for inline formulas. In that case it's much quicker when you write math.

Comment: It might be faster to type, but now your missing the clear separation between text and math in your code. So I agree with campa, not recommendable.

Comment: Thank you @daleif, I'll make sure I won't repeat again. Is there any package or tips that would help me in faster typing the manuscript?

Comment: Learn to use the features your editor provides you with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain what  you want with `etoolbox` and the `footnote` package (from the `mdwtools` bundle):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages Required
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% tcolorbox and theorem Environment
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem
  []% init options
  {theorem}% name
  {Theorem}% title
  {%
    colback=green!5,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
  }% options
  {thm}% prefix

\makeatletter
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% User defined Commands
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{$f(#1)$}
\newcommand{\tcb@cnt@theoremautorefname}{Theorem}
\makeatother

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{\spewnotes}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{13cm}

\begin{theorem}{Cauchy's Theorem}{}
Let C be a simple\footnote{A simple curve is one which does not cross itself.}. closed curve with continously turning tangents except possibly at a finite number of of points (otherwise curve must be smooth). If \f{z} is analytic on and inside C, then
\begin{equation}
\oint_{C} f(z) \, dz = 0
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of using `∮` instead of `\oint`, `Let C be` instead of `Let $C$ be` , `and inside C,` instead of `and inside $C$,` and `f(z) \, dz` instead of `f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: For  the first point, sorry, I didn't pay attention to what my editor was  displaying. It is configured to do some ‘pretty display’, i.e. when it reads `\oint`, it displays `∮` (but saves the code as \oint). For the other points, I simply copied the code in the O.P., and didn't check whether  this code corresponded to the image.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: What's is the difference between $dz$ and $\mathdrm{d}z$, since I don't find much difference between them. Please enlighten me, so that I can write better syntax. Any source for math-texing is fine.

Comment: @Bernard your solution work great for short tcolorbox environments. But with `breakable` environments the footnote shows up after the box has been break. If the footnote call is at the beginning of the box, the footnote appears in the wrong page. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: And the footnote mark is not in sync with general footnotes