Can paragraph bars be made to meet in the quote environment?
I was trying to save space in long quotations, as opposed to having margins on both left and right sides, to have one on the left only and add a vertical line, similar to as seen in internet content. Not sure if a good or bad idea but that is not the question.
I started from the vertbars package (which starts from lineno package) and it works well for the quotation environment but not for quote; because, in quote, the lines don't meet to fill the vertical space between paragraphs.
(I'm not using the quote envionment but the same applies if add vertical space within the quotation env.; and it is needed because some of the quotations are letters that require a bit of vertical space, such as between the date and content.)
My questions:

Can the parargraph bars be made to meet and fill that space?
Can the vertbars concept be applied to the environment rather than the individual pargraphs?
Is there a better method.

Thank you.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\usepackage{vertbars}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\color{mygray}}
% \renewcommand{\linenumbersep}{-2em}
\linenumbersep=-2em
\renewcommand{\barwidth}{3pt}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\begin{vertbar}}
\AtEndEnvironment{quotation}{\end{vertbar}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\begin{vertbar}}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\end{vertbar}}

\begin{document}
Some text to lead into the quotation. \lipsum[1][2]
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\lipsum[3][1-3]
\end{quotation}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\lipsum[3][1-3]
\end{quote}

\end{document}




Tried this also from this answer but it's not a quote environemt any longer; but it provides a single continuous vertical bar.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{200,200,200}

\newcommand{\linedquote}[1]{
  \mbox{\color{mygray} \vrule width 3pt \hspace{1em}%
  \color{black}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth - 2\parindent}
   #1
  \end{minipage}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\lipsum[20][1-5]

\begin{linedquote}{
 \lipsum[20][1-3]

 \vspace{\baselineskip}

 \lipsum[3][1-3]

 \vspace{\baselineskip}

 \lipsum[4][1-3]
}\end{linedquote}

\end{document}



Added later:
This handles the footnotes in the mdframe manually, so to speak, and ties them in with the rest of the document rather than separately. It does not answer the question about vertbars but it works. I'm sure there is a better way. However, it the quote spans pages and there is a footnote on the first page, it will appear on the second page.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 letterpaper,
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{mdframed,lipsum}
\newmdenv[
linecolor = blue,
linewidth = 4pt,
topline = false,
bottomline = false,
rightline = false,
innertopmargin = 0pt,
innerbottommargin = 0pt,
innerrightmargin = 40pt,
innerleftmargin = 40pt,
]{quotebar}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is a non-framed footnote before to the frame.}

\begin{quotebar}
\lipsum[1]\footnotemark\par
\parskip 2ex
\lipsum[2-3] \footnotemark
\end{quotebar}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{This is the first framed footnote.}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{This is the second framed footnote.}

\lipsum[3]\footnote{This is a non-framed footnote after to the frame.}

\end{document}



This answer does not answer how to get the vertbars package to fill the gaps but it does provide another means to accomplish the same that uses the framed pacakge; and \parskip causes no issues. However, after using lineno and vertbars package for the case of interest, I liked the line numbers better because it indicated that a long quote with breaks was continued afterward.

You could use tcolorbox:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{200,200,200}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand{\myfootnotemark}{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotemark[\thefootnote]\setcounter{mycount}{\value{footnote}}}
\newcommand{\firstfootnotetext}[1]{\footnotetext[\themycount]{#1}}
\newcommand{\otherfootnotetext}[1]{\stepcounter{mycount}\footnotetext[\themycount]{#1}}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    blanker, 
    left skip=1.3em,
    left=-1.3em,
    borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{mygray},
    breakable,
    #1}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\begin{mybox}}
\AtEndEnvironment{quotation}{\end{mybox}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\begin{mybox}}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\end{mybox}}

\begin{document}
Some text to lead into the quotation. \lipsum[1][2]\footnote{This is the first note outside the boxes}

\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]\myfootnotemark

\lipsum[3][1-3]\footnotemark

\lipsum[3][1-3]\footnotemark

\lipsum[3][1-3]\footnotemark

\lipsum[3][1-3]\footnotemark
\end{quotation}
\firstfootnotetext{This is the first note inside the box}
\otherfootnotetext{This is another note inside the box second}
\otherfootnotetext{This is another note inside the box third}
\otherfootnotetext{This is another note inside the box fourth}
\otherfootnotetext{This is another note inside the box fifth}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2][1-3]\footnotemark

\lipsum[3][1-3]
\end{quote}
\footnotetext{This is a second note inside the box}

On more pages:\footnote{This is another note outside the boxes}

\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[1]\myfootnotemark

\lipsum[1][1-3]\footnotemark

\lipsum[1]\footnotemark
\end{quotation}
\firstfootnotetext{This is a third note inside the box}
\otherfootnotetext{This is another footnote inside the box}
\footnotetext{This is a third footnote inside the box}

Outside\footnote{Final footnote outside the boxes}
\end{document}



Thank you. I looked at this (in the text I have) before posting the question; and I don't know how I missed these details, just plain stupid of me. I figured there had to be something like CSS in which the borders could be varied independently and, now, I see that even the corners can be rounded like a border radius.  Thank you for the example.

@Gary You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer!

Is it possible for an mbox, like this, to span pagebreaks? I'll look into it, of course; and the box also causes any footnotes in the quote to be placed near the box under a different numbering sequence rather than at the bottom of the page. Just noting that there will be issue to work out depending upon the details.

@Gary It is possible to break across the pages, there is a breakable option. For the footnotes you can use footnote package, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520076/101651. See my renewed anser.

Thank you. I found a way earlier using mdframed but had to use \footnotemark and \footnotetext; and, if when more than one footnote in the quote, had to use \addtocounter{footnote}{-n} and then increment upward after each \footnotetext. It works; but your solution appears better.  I cannot read the footnote numbers or symbols in your example output to see how they are incrementing.

@Gary Here a link where you can see better the numbers: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dbjxkpthjshx#f5e79a

Thank you. I'm not asking for further information; I just aded the code to show what I was trying to explain. You pointed me in the right direction and the details are my problem to work out, or ask a new question if I can't. Thanks for your help.

@Gary I found a solution with \footnotemark and \footnotetext. In case there are more than one note in the box, use \myfootnotemark the first \footnotemark and \firstfootnotetext for the first footnote text and \otherfootnotetext for the other footnote texts of the box.

Thank you very much. I will try to work it into my project in the next couple days. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to figure it out.

@Gary There is still a problem I cannot solve, I asked a question for it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723997/how-to-put-a-note-inside-a-multi-page-tcolorbox-on-the-page-where-is-mentioned

@Gary Here's the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611437/101651

Thanks, again, for all your help and for digging into these extra items. I haven't added it to my project, yet, but this is where I left off with the mdframed version--had it working, I thought, until realizing that, when the footnote spanned across a page break, a footnote on the start page appeared on the end page. Evidently, this solves that issue and I will attempt to employ it soon. Thank you.

@Gary You're welcome!
