How to put a note inside a multi-page tcolorbox on the page where is mentioned?
In the following MWE, how can I have note 2 at the bottom of page 1 instead of page 3 where it is now?
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    Something before\footnote{A note outside the box}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
      \blindtext
     
      Something inside the box\footnotemark
      
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
      \blindtext
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \footnotetext{A note in the box}

    Something after\footnote{Another note outside the box}
\end{document}




There is also this approach

@JasperHabicht That's a solution!
