# Footnotes with tcolorbox

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

I would like to know how to put footnotes outside of a tcolorbox.
A simple example of what I get with the usual footnote command :

[image]:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
this is text\footnote{and a footnote inside the box} but I would like to have this footnote at the end of the page
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481317/footnote-outside-tikzbox-and-tcolorbox

Comment: welcome-- please have alook at the answer below -- adapted from -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520067/footnote-outside-theorem-environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{footnote}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\spewnotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        this is text\footnote{and a footnote inside the box} but I would like to have this footnote at the end of the page
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot !

Comment: would you like to accept the answer if it is suitable to you r requirement

Comment: Sure, it should be good now